# Different Anchor Results in Scene Builder and Application

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I generated the following FXML in Scene Builder. When I preview it in Scene Builder and resize the window the inner split view maintains the spacing between itself and the anchor view. However when I run the FXML in my application it does not. Any ideas? I am using javafx 2.2.51.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="477.0" prefWidth="515.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.nm.haze.LibraryViewController">
  <children>
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.09484536082474226" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="487.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="48.0">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
          <children>
            <ListView prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="425.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And my controller code:

```
package com.nm.haze;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LibraryViewController extends BaseController {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

Main code

```
private static final String LIBRARY_SELECT = "LibrarySelect";
private static final String LIBRARY_VIEW = "LibraryView";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    SceneController sceneController = new SceneController(primaryStage, new SettingsManager());
    sceneController.loadScene(LIBRARY_SELECT);
    sceneController.loadScene(LIBRARY_VIEW);
    if (sceneController.setupNeeded()) {
        sceneController.setScreen(LIBRARY_SELECT);
    } else {
        sceneController.setScreen(LIBRARY_VIEW);
    }
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(sceneController);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

SceneController code:

```
public class SceneController extends StackPane {

Map<String, Node> scenes = new HashMap<>();
Stage stage;
SettingsManager settingsManager;

public SceneController(Stage stage, SettingsManager settingsManager) {
    this.stage = stage;
    this.settingsManager = settingsManager;
}

public void addScene(String name, Node scene) {
    scenes.put(name, scene);
}

public void loadScene(String name) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(name + ".fxml"));
    Parent loadScreen = (Parent)myLoader.load();
    ((BaseController)myLoader.getController()).setSceneController(this);
    addScene(name, loadScreen);
}

public void setScreen(final String name) {
    List<Node> children = getChildren();
    Node scene = scenes.get(name);
    if(scene != null) {
        if (children.size() > 0) {
            children.remove(0);
        }
        children.add(0, scene);

    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Scene has not been loaded");
    }
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
}

public boolean setupNeeded() {
    return settingsManager.setupNeeded();
}

}
```

Just to be clear about what the issue is, please see the before and after screenshots below. The distance between the `ListView` and the `AnchorPane` should stay the same (and does in Scene Builder).

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the interest of ruling things out, would you mind posting the controller code in LibraryViewController.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You just have to fix the minimum and maximum width of the part of the SplitPane, whose width you dont want to change on resizing your window !

Here I have fixed the left part, by setting the `minWidth` and `maxWidth` of `AnchorPane on the left side`. You can do the same for the right side as well, depending on your requirement.

**abcFxml.fxml**

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="477.0" prefWidth="515.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="bounty.LibraryViewController">
  <children>
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.09484536082474226" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="415.0" prefWidth="487.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="48.0">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="100.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" maxHeight="160.0" maxWidth="100.0" />
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
          <children>
            <ListView prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="425.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LibraryViewController extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("abcFxml.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        arg0.setScene(scene);
        arg0.show();

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Screenshots**

*Size1*

[image]

*Size 2*

[image]

**EDIT** : *As per user updation*

The problem you are facing is because of the `Group` you are using. Group itself is not resizable ! Try to put the StackPane directly to your scene(like I did) or you can use any other container like `VBOX` / `HBOX` etc

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    SceneController sceneController = new SceneController(primaryStage, new SettingsManager());
    sceneController.loadScene(LIBRARY_SELECT);
    sceneController.loadScene(LIBRARY_VIEW);
    if (sceneController.setupNeeded()) {
        sceneController.setScreen(LIBRARY_SELECT);
    } else {
        sceneController.setScreen(LIBRARY_VIEW);
    }
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sceneController));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, see screenshots above.

Comment: @shortspider Please look at the updated answer, I have also attached screenshots with two different screen sizes !

Comment: so your code works just like I want it, when I run it as as its own application. In my application I have a scene controller which handles scene switching for me. Please look at my edits. THIS doesn't work. I know its outside the scope of the original question but do you know what's going on?